# Database gets populated on page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

I have a script which validates and submits the data to the MySQL database but whenever the Index page is refreshed or revisited in a new tab in both the case the database gets populated. The populated data is BLANK. I want to stop this automated resubmission of data but not sure how to do it.

This is my script that validates and submits the data to the database.

```
<?php include('includes/config.php');
    // define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $contactErr = $cityErr = $serviceErr = "";
$name = $contact = $city = $service = "";

function test_input($data) 
  {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
  }

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "* Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "* Only letters and white space allowed";
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["contact"])) {
     $contactErr = "* Contact is required";
   } else {
     $contact = test_input($_POST["contact"]);
     // check if contact number is well-formed
     if (!preg_match("/^[0-9+]*$/",$contact)) {
       $contactErr = "* Phone number should contain only numbers";
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
     $cityErr = "* City is required";
   } else {
     $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
     // check if city is valid
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
       $cityErr = "* Only letters and white space allowed";
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["service"])) {
     $serviceErr = "* Service is required";
   } else {
     $service = test_input($_POST["service"]);
   }
 } 

    $myDb->connect();
    $query = "INSERT INTO user_profile (name, city, contact, service)VALUES('$name', '$city', '$contact', '$service')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $myDb->close();
    $display_error = "Data submitted successfully."; 


?>
```

This is my form.

```
 <form action="index.php"  method="post">

    <table style="line-height: 50px;">
        <tr>
          <th>Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" style="height:30px; border:1px; width:300px; border-radius:5px; text-indent:15px"><span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <br>
        <tr>
          <th>Phone&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
          <td><input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Your Contact Number" style="height:30px; border:1px; width:300px; border-radius:5px; text-indent:15px"><span class="error"> <?php echo $contactErr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>City&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
          <td><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Your City Name" style="height:30px; border:1px; width:300px; border-radius:5px; text-indent:15px"><span class="error"> <?php echo $cityErr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Service&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
          <td><select name="service" autocomplete="off" style="height:30px; border:1px; width:300px; border-radius:5px;">
              <option value="">Select your service</option>
              <option value=service1>Service 1</option>
              <option value=service2>Service 2</option>
              <option value=service3>Service 3</option>
              <option value=service4>Service 4</option>
              </select><span class="error"> <?php echo $serviceErr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="height: 40px; width: 140px; border-radius: 5px; margin-left: 140px;margin-top: 20px;">
    </form>
```

I don't know what mistake I am making. Everytime I open my index.php page that contains the form, automatically a new BLANK DATABASE is added. How can I prevent this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`$myDb->connect();
$query = "INSERT INTO user_profile (name, city, contact, service)VALUES('$name',  '$city','$contact', '$service')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$myDb->close();
$display_error = "Data submitted successfully.";`

This should be inside the if statement

Comment: this statement should be inside the if statement where you check if the request is POST,also check if you got any error before executing this code.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
```

To

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```